# Apply function over rows in pandas df

Tags: python, function, pandas

In a pandas df, I have a column `['name']` with various Operating System classifications such as `'Windows 7', 'Windows 10', 'Linux', 'Mobile iOS 9.1', 'OS X 10.12'`, etc. That are strings.

I am hoping to use this function to create a new column `['type']` that will be a more generalized version:

```
def name_group(row):
    if 'Windows' in row:
        name = 'Microsoft Windows'
    elif 'iOS' in row:
        name = 'Apple iOS'
    elif 'OS X' in row:
        name ='Apple Macintosh'
    elif 'Macintosh' in row:
        name = 'Apple Macintosh'
    elif 'Linux' in row:
        name = 'GNU/Linux'
    else:
        name = 'Other'
    return name
```

It works correctly when I test the function by passing in a single string variable, but for some reason when I apply the function to the df like this, it only returns "other" for each row.

```
new_df['type'] = new_df.apply(name_group, axis=1)
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass column `name` with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
new_df['type'] = new_df['name'].apply(name_group)
```

But if want use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) then need `lambda` function and pass name of column too:

```
new_df['type'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: name_group(x['name']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. The only modification is I needed to change the 'return name' at the end of the function to 'return str(name)'