# Pandas: Applying function to rows, writing into new columns

Tags: python, function, loops, dataframe

Applying functions to dataframe

I currently have following dataframe:

**Data**

```
url                            visitors
http://somedomain.com          200000
http://someotherdomain.com     150000
http://somenewdomain.com       11000
```

For every row in the dataframe, I like to apply two functions to the url column and then write each result in two distinct columns 'meta' and 'content'.

**Functions:**

```
def metacrawler(url)
    ...
    return data

def contentcrawler(url)
    ...
    return data

# Counter
progress = 0
```

**Loop**

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(str(progress)," out of ",str(len(data)))
    print('Starting meta crawling.')
    row['meta'] = metacrawler(row["url"])
    print('Starting content crawling.')
    row['content'] = contentcrawler(row["url"])
    print('Complete.')
    progress += 1
```

However, when I aborted the process after few iterations, I found that no data was written into the data frame. No columns were created either.

What did I do wrong?

***Solution***

```
def func(row):
    print("Crawling Meta")
    meta = metacrawler(row["url"])
    print("Crawling Content")
    tags = contentcrawler(row["url"])
    return meta, content

data[['meta', 'content']] = data.apply(func, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply function over rows in pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352482/apply-function-over-rows-in-pandas-df)

Comment: But this doesn't show any progress, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.apply()` function [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `result_type='expand'`

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4], 'two':[5,6,7,8]})

In [4]: df.apply(lambda x: (sum(x), sum(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')
Out[4]:
    0   1
0   6   6
1   8   8
2  10  10
3  12  12

In [5]: df[['new', 'etc']] = df.apply(lambda x: (sum(x), sum(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   one  two  new  etc
0    1    5    6    6
1    2    6    8    8
2    3    7   10   10
3    4    8   12   12
```

Edit:
If you want to show progress, define the applied function separately i.e.

```
def func(row):
    print(row)
    return sum(row), sum(row)


In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4], 'two':[5,6,7,8]})

In [4]: df.apply(func), axis=1, result_type='expand')
Out[4]:
    0   1
0   6   6
1   8   8
2  10  10
3  12  12

In [5]: df[['new', 'etc']] = df.apply(lambda x: (sum(x), sum(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   one  two  new  etc
0    1    5    6    6
1    2    6    8    8
2    3    7   10   10
3    4    8   12   12
```

Comment: Yes, I looked into that. I'm just curious how I can see the progress then?

Comment: See my edit above, you can do anything you like in the applied function

Comment: NoteI added another example above. However, this doesn't work either. When I aborted the script after a few iterations, I discovered nothing has been written into data :/

Comment: `apply()` operates on each row of the data set, there is no need to run it in a for loop

Comment: But the point is that my url list is pretty long and scraping takes some time. I like to track and see the progress.

Comment: Please see the edit example at the bottom of my answer, replace the lambda function with a defined function and call a print statement, this will print something for each row.

Comment: I saw that one, I just can't see where the new df cols are created and how I call this function?

Comment: See the full example above

Comment: Thanks, added solution above.